# Mouse wheel sensitivty, Razer Abyssus

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel

How do I increase the mouse wheel sensitivity? I have a razer Abysuss and I hate this problem in windows which was fixed by install the razer drivers, but they don't support Linux so what are my options? I'm not looking to change it in just firefox or one program but on the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this tool:

http://bues.ch/cms/hacking/razercfg.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good answer (it works for me) : http://patrickmylund.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/

Comment: it would be great if you post the directions in your answer along with the link. Also does this work on the latest ubuntu version?